# What does load average statement mean in sendmail log? Current LA? Or Threshold?

Tags: centos, email, smtp, sendmail, load-average

In sendmail logs, I'm seeing events like:

```
Mar 20 08:36:05 foo sendmail_daemon_foo[1234]: rejecting connections on daemon MTA: load average: 50
```

Does this mean that the connection was rejected because the current load average on the system **was 50**? Or does this mean the connection was rejected because the current load average on the system **exceeded a sendmail threshold of 50**?

I have dual Xeon processors with 8 cores.  As far as I know, sendmail throttles connections based on a couple formulas (as per http://www.sendmail.org/m4/tweaking_config.html):

- By default, messages are queued when load average reaches 8 * number of procs
- By default messages are rejected when load average reaches 12 * number of procs

I don't have any special configurations so I wouldn't have thought there to be issues unless LA was at least 64.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you give a larger log snippet, for context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [configuration README](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/configuration_readme/) states:

- confQUEUE_LA QueueLA [varies] Load average at which queue-only function kicks in. Default values is (8 * numproc) where numproc is the number of processors online (**if that can be determined**).
- confREFUSE_LA RefuseLA [varies] Load average at which incoming SMTP connections are refused.  Default values is (12 * numproc) where numproc is the number of processors online (**if that can be determined**).

It is best to set these values "by hand" in *sendmail.mc* and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @adamo.  My concern is that I'm not sure what the values should be.  Any thoughts?

Comment: `cat /proc/cpuinfo` to determine how many processors the operating system is seeing. Then do the appropriate defines using the multipliers stated in the documentation. Depending the behavior of your system under heavy load you may want to lower them a bit, but you have to experiment. Also, if you experience high loads, you may also want to consider implementing multiple queues. Depending your case you may also consider [this setup](http://serverfault.com/a/349453/25640)

Comment: ahhh.  So CPU cores can actually count as "processors".  Makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: One more question: with regard to the warning, is 50 the load average it observed at the time?  Or is that the threshold sendmail set for itself?

Comment: It is the current (but depends on the LA_TYPE compile-time option), but as the bat book says _"these options rely on the system load average, which can generally be sluggish and can lag behind events."_

Answer (score 0):

Load average is the number of processes waiting to run, if that number gets too high, `sendmail` refuses to accept more mail (that would increase the load on the machine still furter). Contrary to what users expect, email is *not* instantaneous, waiting a bit for the peak load to subside is a smart move.